# How to stop PHP process in windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I am running `PHP using XAMPP on Windows` I have this PHP page called `interface.php`which calls another PHP script `proxy.php` using `ajax`.

It is something like `$.get("proxy.php");`

Now `proxy.php` just does `exec(php process.php)`;

Everything works fine here. I press a button in interface.php, the ajax call is made to proxy.php, which starts executing process.php and returns a message to interface that the process has begun.

My question is, sometimes I need to kill the `process.php`. I can do it manually, no need for automation. I need to kill it because while testing, I see something wrong so I fix it and want to restart. Now when I check `task manager` I see nothing related to `process.php`. I end the `httpd.exe` and `xampp-control.exe` from task manager but the process still runs till it ends.

How can I kill this `php script` when I need to?

Comment: Stop the Apache2 service.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - what do you think ending `httpd.exe` does?

Comment: It should kill the webserver (apache).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - So I have already mentioned that I am doing that and that it is not helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look for `php.exe` in the task manager. `exec('php')` is equivalent to manually typing `php` in CLI: a "standalone" (independent of the web server) php.exe process is started with CLI SAPI.

Comment: hero - needed to refresh php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can't but you can modify you php.ini with set_time_limit to have it done automatically if it takes too long.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: In the default php.ini is max_execution_time set to 30 (seconds). I think he changed the value.